# What does "Brewed with the finest ingredients since 1982" mean?

Tags: meaning

```
Brewed with the finest ingredients since 1982
```

Does it mean:

"Since 1982, we have been brewing with the finest ingredients"

"We brewed this with ingredients, the ingredients being the finest since 1982"

"We brewed this with the finest ingredients, and those ingredients have existed in the year 1982 and beyond."

Comment: It means the stuff has been brewing for a long time.  Probably scorched by now.

Comment: your dictionary finding of to brew?

Comment: If it means anything other than '"Since 1982, we have been brewing this beer, and have always used the finest ingredients" I can see the FSA and/or ASA getting involved.

Comment: It could mean some tea is brewed simultaneously alongside some ingredients for, say, crystal meth, which are the least coarse such ingredients available, on account of the death of Leonid Brezhnev. You cannot know with certainty the meaning of much at all without additional context, though a reasonable person can make reasonable assumptions about what a producer would put on a product label.

Comment: It means they think 1982 was a long time ago, and they think the stuff their supplier ships them is the finest, because they checked that box on the order form.

Comment: Another literal way to read the statement is that the brewer has been using the finest ingredients since 1982—but in the years prior to that, the ingredients used were second rate at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that "We've been brewing since 1982 and we've always brewed with the finest ingredients."

Comment: That's what we'd like to believe!

Comment: But it's true! I read it on the internet

Comment: Hello, Jordan. Please read the information at the 'Help Center' about the sort of questions considered suitable for ELU. Hopefully, this question will soon be closed. // 'Brewed' indicates a product; it's most unlikely that 'We have' has been deleted here.

Comment: How do you know it's that one and not the others?

Comment: Because the main statement is "Brewed since 1982". "With the finest ingredients" serves to add detail to "brewed".